# How to run post configuration code in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my tests i need to some static configuration (rest client). This code should run after all the config files are loaded but before any test. it doesn't produce any bean.

```
@TestConfiguration
class Config {
  
        // how to annotate this method? @PostConstruct won't work. it's not a @Bean as it's void
        fun postConfiguration(env: Environment) {
           SomeClass.staticField = env.getProperty("xyz")
        }

    }
```

How to make this method executed?

Comment: `@Autowired` above your method will do the trick.

Comment: @tashkhisi indeed, thank you! if u add an answer, i'll accept

Comment: Is `SomeClass` in a third-party library you can't change?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic yes, i need to setup external library for tests. but does it change anything? what are the options if it's my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Autowired` annotation will do the trick you can do that like this:

```
@TestConfiguration
class Config {

    @Autowired
    fun postConfiguration(env: Environment) {
        SomeClass.staticField = env.getProperty("xyz")
    }

}
```